# Image blur in Firemonkey

Tags: image, delphi, firemonkey

I use some professional image to do my little application.

I want to use the 24x24 image, I add it in design time.

When I launch it from Windows or Android, my image is blur. With a bigger image of 260x170 that's ok. That's do it for my 16x16 and 24x24 icons.

[image]

Can I do something with that ?

Comment: On your screenshot is a scaled image, not just blurred (the image is not 24x24px anymore). There are many algorithms for image scaling where some of them can produce result like you've shown on your image.

Comment: Just make sure that it is shown at its original size. Either resize the component to the right size, or if you use a component with a TImageWrapMode property (e.g. TImage), set the WrapMode = Original.

Comment: I set it to "Original", in 32x32 that's better but not enought good, in 16 or 24x24 that's better too but not perfect, then it's ok in Windows now.